# deploying web application using AWS RDS

Tags: jsp, amazon-s3, web-hosting, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-rds

Environment : My database is on AWS RDS of MySQL type. The rest of of pages are jsp(The main logic as well as the HTML content is both embedded n jsp pages, Also note : I am creating a Project in eclipse of type : AWS Java Web Project). Now I wish to deploy this project on the Internet for real time use.

I am aware of the following ways, but cant decide which way suits my above mentioned needs. :

Option 1) Deploy the application using AWS CloudFront - But here I am not sure if CloudFront renders jsp pages, also does it support the fact that my database is on RDS.

Option 2) Deploy the application using Elastic BeanStalk - But there is not much help provided  to deploy a Web application in the AWS manuals. So I am not sure how to go about this.

Option 3) Upload my jsp pages on some other free webhost such as freeserver.com or bluehost(Please also suggest if you know any yet better web host). But here I am not sure of security since my pages have code where I am passing URL, Username and password to the connection object(I obv dont want any other third person to be able to get access to my RDS  database instance using the info passed to the connection object).

Please help as I am working on AWS for the first time and hence I am getting messed up with its wide range of services.

Answer (score 0):

You need a servlet container to serve your jsp pages. 1) and 2) are not intended for this. iii) Keeping everything in AWS, create an `EC2` instance. Deploy apache/tomcat or any other webserver/servlet container on your EC2 instance. This will be your server which you will be able to access over the internet using public_ip:port
Use a micro instance if you are not going to see a lot of traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Just to help other visitors of the post:

Option 2) Deploy the application using Elastic BeanStalk - But there is not much help provided to deploy a Web application in the AWS manuals. So I am not sure how to go about this.

1. Open your Elastic BeansTalk -> Create New Application, Give it a Name.
2. Environments -> Create New one--> Web Server Environment-->Environment Information-> Fill in all details.
3. Enter a domain name(check availability has to be green is a success),Choose your platform (can choose Tomcat). Upload your zipped code(I had seen issues with rar, so just zip with default windows options and upload)--> Click "Create Environment".
4. Wait until it is being processed and the Health turns to Green OK.
5. If green OK, On the same screen where you see health status, just above that you will see Environment ID and a URL. Click the url and you should see your application launched.

*** Please make a note of the Security Access Key, Access Key ID During the above steps, AWS will offer you to dowload credentials.csv***

Additional FYIs:
1. If you want to deploy directly from netbeans : Services->cloud-> add new cloud and you should see Amazon Elastic BeansTalk already->click on it and provide your Security Access Key and Key ID. Done!
2. Create new Project and while you choose your server choose your elastic beansTalk web server that automatically populates with the elastic beans instance that you just created in AWS(Above 5 steps). Done! Now on whenever you make changes and redeploy, you don't have to re upload your zipped project. In a browser open your elastic beanstalk instance open and you see it refreshing every time you redeploy in your IDE.

All the best!